# Editing a QGIS Project overwrites the Project Template

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, template

after opening a project from a template:
Project> New from template> (select template)
and then adding features to the new project, the features are also added to the original template.
when the features are deleted from the template, they are also deleted from the new project.
I am using save as to save the new project so it has a different name to the template in a different location. Somehow the two are linked?